# Не корректно работает слайдер. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slick.js

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы .slick-current менял свой размер плавно? При прокрутке он должен становиться меньше, чем другие картинки, но у меня все как-то враскорячку, хоть он и становится меньше, но медленно или слишком быстро, в общем не хорошо. Извините, с размерами особо не заморачивалась, но я думаю суть ясна:) Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
        dots:true,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        variableWidth: true,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
    });
  });
```

```css
.slick-track {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.slick-list {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slick-current.slick-active img{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="https://cdnn.1prime.ru/images/83410/76/834107650.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ad/Savannah_Cat_closeup.jpg/800px-Savannah_Cat_closeup.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="https://n1s2.hsmedia.ru/43/8e/85/438e85e1dcf8bc45fdb4738ad67e0523/728x485_1_676f156728d52a40cefbf4e88311021a@5000x3333_0xac120003_744610521626771276.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Из-за кривой верстки сложно понять что там происходит. Вы это хотели сделать?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
        dots:true,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        variableWidth: true,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
    });
  });
```

```css
.slick-track {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.slick-list {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.slider__item.slick-active{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.slider__item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.slider__item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="https://cdnn.1prime.ru/images/83410/76/834107650.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ad/Savannah_Cat_closeup.jpg/800px-Savannah_Cat_closeup.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="https://n1s2.hsmedia.ru/43/8e/85/438e85e1dcf8bc45fdb4738ad67e0523/728x485_1_676f156728d52a40cefbf4e88311021a@5000x3333_0xac120003_744610521626771276.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```